# Building Identical apps in Xcode for the iphone 4 and the iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, iphone-4

I have been doing a lot of research on build an app for both the iphone 4 and iphone 5.  I have posted a link for another question I posted.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666780/deploying-my-app-for-both-the-iphone-4-and-iphone-5

Here is a follow up question. I have been thinking of creating two identical apps.  The only difference is one would be set up for the iphone 4 and the other would be set up for the iphone 5.  Is this a good idea and would apple accept both the apps?

Comment: If they are identical, why would you want to do so? Did you know that you can distinguish the device at runtime so you can load different kind of images? Anyway, it's not a good idea to create an application only for old devices, and I think it will become a requirement to support the iphone5 and retina display in a short time.

Comment: No, it's not a good idea. One app that supports 3.5" and 4.0" screens is a far superior approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea.  First off Apple would not allow the two different applications and even if they did there is nothing stopping an iPhone 4 user from downloading your iPhone 5 Version or visa versa.  The best way to go about handling the differences between sizes is either through the nib /storyboard or programmatically within a single application.

Answer (score 0):

From 1st of May Apple will reject all apps which don't support 4", so this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You must read the notices given by apple

Here are the notices:

> Starting May 1, the App Store will no longer accept new apps or app updates that access UDIDs. Please update your apps and servers to associate users with the Vendor or Advertising identifiers introduced in iOS 6
>
> Starting May 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built for iOS devices with Retina display and iPhone apps must also support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5

So, Even if you upload same app for both iPhone4 & 5 & got success, you will be forced to take back all such kinda apps otherwise apple will reject all those on 1st of may..